# creating dynamic input fields using jquery in not working for select type inputs

Tags: jquery

I am creating a page which dynamically creates input fields using jquery on the click of add button. It is working for Input field but not working for select field. The select field is as it is repeated without the change of name field. So iam having problem in getting these details via $_GET. Plz give a solution asap.

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<link href="nietsms.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <title> NIET Store Management System BY SDC </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cachefile.net/scripts/jquery/1.2.3/jquery-1.2.3.min.js"></script>



    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            var newRowNum = 0;
            $('#addnew').click(function(){
                newRowNum += 1;
                var addRow = $(this).parent().parent();
                var newRow = addRow.clone();
                $('input', addRow).val('');
                $('td:first-child', newRow).html(newRowNum);
                $('input', newRow).each(function(i){
                    var newID = newRowNum + '_' + i;
                    $(this).attr('id',newID).attr('name',newID);
                });






                addRow.before(newRow);
```

Comment: When it repeats the row all the other input fields remain at the same place while the select drop down menu comes down to next row. While it should remain on the initial row only. plz let me know how to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
$('input', addRow)
```

and

```
$('input', newRow)
```

with

```
$(":input", addRow)
```

and

```
$(':input', newRow).
```

`$("input")` returns only nodes of type "input", while ":input" is a jQuery pseudoselector which targets inputs, selects, options etc.

Comment: When it repeats the row all the other input fields remain at the same place while the select drop down menu comes down to next row. While it should remain on the initial row only. plz let me know how to solve this.

Comment: I am afraid it is a markup or style issue, so I cannot know what possibly went wrong.